# Showing the maximum value of a line graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

This is my current graph.
[image]
And, I would like to draw a line to show the maximum value of the graph, also the value in x axis. Which would look like this:
[image]

I can manually draw the line by plotting the line, but I am stuck in writing its value in the x axis. This is the best I came up with:

[image]

But the additional text is not on the axes, as can be seen. Is there a way to show the desired output and make the additoinal text look more natural on the axes? Is there a function that does it?

The code:

```
max_y = max(y)
max_x = []
for i in list(new_dict.keys()):
    if new_dict[i] == max_y:
        max_x.append(i)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot([np.mean(max_x), np.mean(max_x)], [0, max_y], 'r--',label='Highest Probability')
plt.plot([min(x), np.mean(max_x)],[max_y,max_y],'r--')
plt.text(np.mean(max_x),0,str(np.mean(max_x)),fontsize='x-large')
plt.text(min(x),np.mean(max_y),str(np.mean(max_y)),fontsize='x-large')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[You can find the data here](https://jpst.it/1Jn_f)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please (1) provide the data you're using and (2) provide the code you're using to plot this?  It would help us answer your question correctly as we can just modify your code to generate the desired plot instead of us having to do it from the beginning.

Comment: @rayryeng you are right. But the data is just too big that I thought it would be bad to put it here

Comment: Code is enough. Thanks!